# Using GLEW with QOpenGLWidget

Tags: qt, opengl, glew

I'm trying to use GLEW with QT in a QOpenGLWidget in Visual Studio.

Some details:

- Visual Studio 2013
- Glew 2.0.0 x64
- QT 5.6.2 x64

I keep getting "`Missing GL version`" error when calling `glewInit()`. I've searched online a lot, and this problem seems to sometimes be caused by how the format is set (`QSurfaceFormat`), or how the functions `create()`/ `makeCurrent()` / `doneCurrent()` are used. But I can't seem to find a working solution. I'm still a bit confused about the whole `QOpenGLContext` thing also.

I manage to get the `QOpenGLWidget` work without GLEW, and using "old" gl functions (`glBegin()`, `glEnd()`, etc...). And I also get GLEW to work with GLFW3.

Is there something I seem to misunderstand in the code below?

**My subclass of QOpenGLWidget**

**MyGLWidget.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QWidget>
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "qopenglcontext.h"
#include "loadShader.h"

class MyGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
   MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MyGLWidget();

public:
   void initializeGL() override;
   void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
   void paintGL() override;
};
```

**MyGLWidget.cpp**

```
#include "MyGLWidget.h"

MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent)
   : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

   QSurfaceFormat glformat;
   glformat.setVersion(3, 2);
   glformat.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DeprecatedFunctions);
   glformat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
   glformat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
   QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(glformat);
   this->setFormat(glformat);

   create();
   makeCurrent();
}

MyGLWidget::~MyGLWidget(){}

void MyGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
   glewExperimental = TRUE;
   GLenum err = glewInit();
   if (GLEW_OK != err){
      std::cout << "[Error] GLEW failed to initialize. " << (const char*)glewGetErrorString(err);
   }
   doneCurrent();

   GLuint TextShader_ID = LoadShaders("Shaders/TextVertShader.vert", "Shaders/TextFragShader.frag");

}

void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void MyGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
   //...
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "OGLQT_test2.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    OGLQT_test2 w;

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**OGLQT_test2.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_OGLQT_test2.h"
#include "qopenglcontext.h"

class OGLQT_test2 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OGLQT_test2(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::OGLQT_test2Class ui;
};
```

**OGLQT_test2.cpp**

```
#include "OGLQT_test2.h"
#include "MyGLWidget.h"

OGLQT_test2::OGLQT_test2(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    MyGLWidget* glwidget = new MyGLWidget(this);

    glwidget->setFixedHeight(400);
    glwidget->setFixedWidth(500);
    glwidget->move(50, 50);

    glwidget->initializeGL();
    glwidget->resizeGL(400,500);
    glwidget->paintGL();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot do this:

```
glformat.setVersion(x, y);
```

with GLEW. It works with QOpenGLFunctions, but apparently, it doesn't work with GLEW. You may not be able to do this, either:

```
glformat.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DeprecatedFunctions);
glformat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
glformat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
```

Try removing the format.

Also, I think you're doing a little bit of a mess here:

```
glwidget->initializeGL();
glwidget->resizeGL(400,500);
glwidget->paintGL();
```

1. There is a simple way to do this, just do:

```
glwidget->resize(400,500);
glwidget->show();
```

2. resizeGL is an *event* called by `resize`. That goes the same for `initializeGL()` and `paintGL()` being called by `show`.
   Another one is:

```
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err){
   std::cout << "[Error] GLEW failed to initialize. " << (const char*)glewGetErrorString(err);
}
doneCurrent();
```

Now why would you call `doneCurrent` here?